# re-write php post request to java Android post request (and get response)

Tags: java, php, android, curl, post

I want to create this post request from android application, and get the json response:

```
function send_post_to_url($url,$post) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return;
}

$data['api_key'] = YOUR_API_KEY;
$data['action'] = 'TestFunction';
$response = send_post_to_url('https://api.superget.co.il/',$data);
echo $response;
```

How can I do this?

I have tried the following but connect keeps trowing an exception

```
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("https://api.superget.co.il").openConnection()));
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.connect();
```

Comment: try any library for android example http://square.github.io/okhttp/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/guide/PostExample.java

Answer (score 0):

Try my code:

sendPost method:

```
public boolean sendPost(Map<String, Object> params, String urlAddress) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
            }
            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            url = new URL(urlAddress);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            //urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            //urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

            //add reuqest header
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

            //urlConnection.setUseCaches( false );
            //urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );


            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            // Send post request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(postDataBytes); //wr.writeBytes(postData.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            //urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

            /*
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("ddd", "\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            Log.e("ddd", "Post parameters : " + postData.toString());
            Log.e("ddd", "Response Code : " + responseCode); */


            String response = "";
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                response += inputLine;
            in.close();

            //get response
            return response.trim().equals("ok");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Using:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("param1", txtContactNf.getText().toString());
params.put("param2", txtContactNf.getText().toString());
final boolean successSend = nu.sendPost(params, "http://yoursite.com/api.php");
```

In this code if php script say `ok` then we get `true` boolean result. You can easily change it and get json result.

edit: get json result

instead `return response.trim().equals("ok");`

```
String response = "";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
response += inputLine;
in.close();

if(response.equals("no")) return null;

return new JSONObject(response);
```

return type must be JSONObject

Comment: it's not works for me, after initializing a Map instanse with "action" I get a response from the server that he can't recognize my action

Comment: @AndoridBegginer What is response result? Toast or log `response` and say to me.